# upload files using WCF

Tags: c#, wcf

I need a WCF Service to upload large files by user.

Which one of the below gives a more optimized performance

```
  [OperationContract]
  public void UploadFile(Stream inputsreaam);
```

or

```
   [OperationContract]
   public void UploadFile(byte[] buffer);
```

any other suggestions are welcome

Comment: What clients will be consuming the service?

Comment: cant get you? how clients make difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to upload really large files, use the Stream one. If you transfer a 2 Gb file as byte[] this will be loaded to memory on the server and only than you can save it somewhere. With the Stream you can read from client stream and write to file or DB stream on the server with only small chunks of data actually in memory. Back to performance: with really large files and multiple clients byte[] is likely to freeze your server for lack of memory.

You may also find this [tutorial](http://stefanoricciardi.com/2009/08/28/file-transfer-with-wcp/) helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Normally, the first (`Stream` parameter). If you're taking a `Stream` parameter, and you're using an endpoint with WebHttpBinding / WebHttpBehavior (i.e., a Web, or REST endpoint), then the Stream parameter will be bound to the entire request body, with no encoding. In this case, if you're using the second (`byte[]`), the parameter must be encoded as an array depending on the format (for XML, the bytes encoded as base64; for JSON, an actual array of numbers representing the bytes).

If you're not using a Web endpoint, however (i.e., you're using a SOAP endpoint), then the two are fairly similar, as the Stream or the byte[] parameter will be bound to the **SOAP body**, and the SOAP message is already encoded.